# TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...data.map...') - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Please help this react noob. I've been trying to perform get all Rest Api. I tried to research the solution here but none of them seem to work. This is the output I get
error

> [TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...data.map...')]
> Unrecognized event: {"type":"client_log","level":"log","data":["1"]}
> Unrecognized event: {"type":"client_log","level":"log","data":["[object Object]"]}
> Unrecognized event: {"type":"client_log","level":"log","data":["error","[TypeError: undefined is not a >function (near '...data.map...')]"]}

1. The Data seems to be in error and and response is not parsing through into the empty array. The API headers are shown below the code.
2. the map data gives me an TypeError as show above, irrelevant to any method I use.

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]); 
        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
        const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
        /* const [data, setData] = useState(null); */


    useEffect(() => {
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        void async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const url = 'http://192.168.0.176:8080/projectses/';
                const response = await fetch(url, { signal: abortController.signal });
                let details = [
                    ];
                for (var i in response.data) {
                    details.push({ name: i, value: response.data[i] })
                }
                let count = Object.keys(details).length;
                console.log(count);
                console.log(details.toLocaleString());
                setData({ data: details }); 
                console.log(data.toLocaleString());
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error', error);
            }
        }();
        return () => {
            abortController.abort(); // cancel pending fetch request on component unmount
        };
    }, []);
   if (!data) return <Text>No data!</Text>;
    if (isError) return <Text>Something went wrong!</Text>; 

  

   
    return (
        
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {
                data && data.map(project => <Text key={project.project_ID}>{project.project_NAME}</Text>)
            } 
          </View>
       
    );
};
```

The response from the Rest Service as displayed on Postman

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "projectses" : [ {
      "project_ID" : 1,
      "project_NAME" : "Project A",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projectses/1"
        },
        "projects" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projectses/1"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "project_ID" : 2,
      "project_NAME" : "Project B",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projectses/2"
        },
        "projects" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projectses/2"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "project_ID" : 3,
      "project_NAME" : "Internal Project C",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projectses/3"
        },
        "projects" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projectses/3"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "project_ID" : 4,
      "project_NAME" : "Available",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projectses/4"
        },
        "projects" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projectses/4"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "project_ID" : 5,
      "project_NAME" : "Absent",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projectses/5"
        },
        "projects" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projectses/5"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projectses"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/projectses"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you truing to map your projects?

Comment: can you show this output:  ` console.log(details.toLocaleString());` i think your project response is in `response.data._embedded.projectses[i]`

Comment: Hi bakar_dev, the output is shown as Unrecognized event: {"type":"client_log","level":"log","data":[""]}

Comment: Hi, tajammul1996, yes, I'm trying to display all the projects in the that Rest API